# Angular 2 Как создать observable, чтобы при занесении его в subject.next() возвращался результат

Tags: angular2, typescript, observer, rxjs

Создаю Observable и при обращении к нему через .subscribe() происходит получение данных. Но как только пытаюсь отсрочить вызов используя Subject, в .subscribe() возвращается сам объект [image: observable]

Вот код:

```
    export class MyUploaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public uploadFiles(event): void {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    let first = fileList[0];

    let subj: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    subj.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });

    subj.next(this.upload(first));


  }

  private upload(file: File): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      console.log("upload");
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // Данные для загрузки
      const formData: FormData = new FormData();

      // Прикрепляем файл
      formData.append('file', file, file.name);

      // Обработка запроса
      request.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {

          if (request.status !== 200) {
            observer.error(request.response);

            return;
          }

          console.log(request);
          observer.next(JSON.parse(request.response));
          observer.complete();

        }
      };   

      // Настройки запроса
      request.open('POST', `http://mydomain.ru/UploadFile`, true);

      request.send(formData);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subj.next(this.upload(first));
```

Ведет себя вполне логично, this.upload(first) - возвращает Observable поэтому вы и видите там Observable

Если хотите "влить" внутрь потока Subject поток с загрузкой файлов воспользутесь mergeMap

```
let subj: Subject<any> = new Subject();

subj.mergeMap(() => this.upload(file))
    .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
    });

subj.next();
```